# Does converting from HTML input to form_for in Rails change the format?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

the website I am working on was originally coded in HTML, CSS, and Javascript. On one part, there is an email subscription text field. Before, we just had an HTML input section. But now that we are starting to work on the backend, I replaced the input with form_for in Ruby on Rails. But the result doesn't look the same as shown below.

**This is what it should look like:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQWhR.jpg

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<div><p id='textbox'>[TEXT HERE]<br>
<input class='subscribe' type='text' placeholder='Email'>
<input class='subscribe' type='submit' value='Join Us'></p>
</div>
```

**Here's the CSS part:**

```
/* subscribe button */
.subscribe {
border: 0;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 18px;
display: inline;
margin: 20px;
border-radius: 6px;
border-decoration: none;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.subscribe[type="text"] {
margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.subscribe[type="submit"] {
background: #abd6a5;
border: 2px solid #abd6a5;
color: white;
}

.subscribe[type="submit"]:hover {
-webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .6s;
-moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
-ms-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
-o-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
transition: all ease-in-out .6s;
background: rgba(171, 214, 165, 0.5);
}
```

**This is what it looks like after I replaced input with form_for:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA4cC.jpg

html.erb file code:

```
<div><p id='textbox'>[TEXT HERE]<br>
<%= form_for(@signup) do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email', class: 'subscribe', type: 'text' %>
     <%= f.submit 'Join Us', class: 'subscribe', type: 'submit' %>
<% end %>
</p>
</div>
```

I didn't change the css file at all.

For some reason, the form doesn't seem to be inside the

section. Is there something that I'm doing wrong or something I can do to fix it?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's no form tag in the original HTML, just a div. Maybe you can use css to place the form tag where you want it if you wish to keep using ruby tags.

If not, you can keep the original HTML and submit via jQuery.

Comment: Hello, would you mind explaining to me what you mean by adding a form tag? do u mean i should replace form_for?

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)